# Two containers within same pod on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a microservice that needs to build a cache on a Redis server upon initialization, fetching data from a MongoDB instance outside the cluster.

Is it a bad practice to put the service and the Redis server in two separate containers on the same pod? Or should they be on different pods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They should be on different pods (and different deployments).

Two reasons for this: you probably want to share a single Redis cache across multiple copies of the service (their scaling properties are different); and you can deploy a prebuilt Redis system (via Helm) without needing to tightly integrate it with your application deployment.

Comment: Could you please be more clear on the last part of your answer? Why would I deploy a prebuilt Redis via helm and what is the disadvantage of defining it on my config files?

Comment: What if I want just one instance of this service running on my cluster? Would placing Redis on the same pod still be a no-go?

Comment: If you already have Helm installed, you can `helm install --name redis stable/redis` and be done, or include Redis in your chart’s `requirements.yaml`, with the main advantage of not needing to write or maintain the deployment yourself.

Comment: Best practice would still be to run your application and Redis separately.  Consider that during a rolling update of your Deployment you will wind up with two copies of it even if you “only want one instance”.